# How to find out which DataGridView rows are currently onscreen?

Tags: c#, datagridview, virtualmode

In my C# (2010) application I have a DataGridView in Virtual Mode which holds several thousand rows.  Is it possible to find out which cells are onscreen at the moment?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
public void GetVisibleCells(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        var visibleRowsCount = dgv.DisplayedRowCount(true);
        var firstDisplayedRowIndex = dgv.FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex;
        var lastvisibleRowIndex = (firstDisplayedRowIndex + visibleRowsCount) - 1;
        for (int rowIndex = firstDisplayedRowIndex; rowIndex <= lastvisibleRowIndex; rowIndex++)
        {
            var cells = dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells;
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in cells)
            {
                if (cell.Displayed)
                {
                    // This cell is visible...
                    // Your code goes here...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Updated**: It now finds visible cells.

Comment: ATTN: You cannot calculate lastvibileRowIndex like that if you are having invisible rows in the grid. In such case you have to check Visible property of row in for-loop and count those visible rows until you reach vivibleRowsCount.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself, but it seems to me that determining the rectangle of a row using [DataGridView.GetRowDisplayRectangle](http://127.0.0.1:47873/help/1-9632/ms.help?method=page&id=M%3aSYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.DATAGRIDVIEW.GETROWDISPLAYRECTANGLE%28SYSTEM.INT32,SYSTEM.BOOLEAN%29&product=VS&productVersion=100&topicVersion=90&locale=EN-US&topicLocale=EN-US) and checking if it overlaps the current [DataGridView.DisplayRectangle](http://127.0.0.1:47873/help/1-9632/ms.help?method=page&id=M%3aSYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.DATAGRIDVIEW.GETROWDISPLAYRECTANGLE%28SYSTEM.INT32,SYSTEM.BOOLEAN%29&product=VS&productVersion=100&topicVersion=90&locale=EN-US&topicLocale=EN-US) would be the way to go. [Rectangle.IntersectsWith](http://127.0.0.1:47873/help/1-9632/ms.help?method=page&id=M%3aSYSTEM.DRAWING.RECTANGLE.INTERSECTSWITH%28SYSTEM.DRAWING.RECTANGLE%29&product=VS&productVersion=100&topicVersion=90&locale=EN-US&topicLocale=EN-US) is useful in to do this.

As an optimization I would use [DataGridView .DisplayedRowCount](http://127.0.0.1:47873/help/1-9632/ms.help?method=page&id=M%3aSYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.DATAGRIDVIEW.DISPLAYEDROWCOUNT%28SYSTEM.BOOLEAN%29&product=VS&productVersion=100&topicVersion=90&locale=EN-US&topicLocale=EN-US) after finding the first visible row to determine what rows are visible.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private bool RowIsVisible(DataGridViewRow row)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = row.DataGridView;
        int firstVisibleRowIndex = dgv.FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex;
        int lastVisibleRowIndex = firstVisibleRowIndex + dgv.DisplayedRowCount(false) - 1;
        return row.Index >= firstVisibleRowIndex && row.Index <= lastVisibleRowIndex;
    }
```

IMHO
Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please explain how it adds anything to the accepted answer from 2011, and how it addresses the comment made to it in 2014 about invisible rows.