# DataGridView Loading Images OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, out-of-memory, virtual

I have got a DataTable bound to a DataGridView. The DataTable is filled with max 30000 rows. The DataGridView should show the content of the DataTable while it is filled, which can take up to 3 minutes, because of some calculation process.

Every Row contains text-cells and two image cells. In the beginning i was loading all images directly to the DataTable, but at some point (~10000 rows) the programm crashed, because the system was out of memory. So i adapted my code a bit. The problem was, that the images are consuming a lot of memory. Now i only load images which can be seen by the user. This helps a lot and the system does not crash anymore loading 30000 rows.

The problem only occures while scrolling heavily through the rows. I set images using the piece of code provided by Alireza Maddah:

```
public void GetVisibleCells(DataGridView dgv)
{´
    ClearImages()
    var vivibleRowsCount = dgv.DisplayedRowCount(true);
    var firstDisplayedRowIndex = dgv.FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex;
    var lastvibileRowIndex = (firstDisplayedRowIndex + vivibleRowsCount) - 1;
    for (int rowIndex = firstDisplayedRowIndex; rowIndex <= lastvibileRowIndex; rowIndex++)
    {
        var cells = dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells;
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in cells)
        {
            if (cell.Displayed)
            {
                // This cell is visible...
                // SET IMAGES TO ROW AND SAVE INDEX
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[How to find out which DataGridView rows are currently onscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045161/how-to-find-out-which-datagridview-rows-are-currently-onscreen)

This piece of code is bound to the scrolling event. I set images if row is visible to the user and i save the index of the row to a list. Before setting the image i call ClearImages().
This function sets all rows which have images to null, using the index entries from list.

I think that setting the variables to null does not free the memory, but this was just my first thought. What do you think? Any ideas?

I can not use paging or virtual mode...

Comment: Have you considered to load thumbnails into the cells instead of the whole image file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to

```
private void ClearNotVisibleImages()
{
   foreach(var row in this.GetNotVisibleDataRowsWithImages())
   {
      var cell = row["Image"];      
      Image image = (Image)(cell .Content);           

      cell.Content = null;
      image.Dispose();
   }


   // If it will be really needed
   GC.Collect();
   // Improved Thanks @rentanadviser
   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
   GC.Collect();
}
```

Comment: I found out that i was setting the wrong cell to null...however i integrated dispose() which improves the performance even more. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

you should use [DataGrid.AllowPaging Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.allowpaging%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to split content pages (e.g 100 images per page) this prevents out of memory exception. You can try to dispose old visible cell images,
also see [GC.Collect() not collecting immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354086/gc-collect-not-collecting-immediately)

Comment: Thank you for your link. I will upvote you and improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the images are not linked by anything. You can also call `GC.Collect()` after clearing  the images to clean up the large object heap. However, that will slow down the responsiveness. Also, I would check first which images are not longer visible and clear only those instead all of them.